# IdentityServer4 throwing error on subsequent login

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4

Moved to .NET 6 and due to ID4 removing the PublicOrigin I went down the workaround of

```
    var publicOrigin = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PublicOrigin");
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin(publicOrigin);
            await next();
        });
```

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4535#issuecomment-647084412

However after the first successful login subsequent logins get the following error.

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> ```
>   at Core.WebApi.Common.Handlers.ApiLoggingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ApiLoggingSettings settings, IConfiguration configuration)
>   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
>   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   at IdentityApp.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<Configure>b__0>d.MoveNext() in
> ```

The entire startup configure method is

```
    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();            
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UsePathBase("/identity");

        var publicOrigin = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PublicOrigin");
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin(publicOrigin);
            await next();
        });

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");
      
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        // Make system event logging explicit opt-in
        if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EnableSystemEventLogging") == true)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ApiLoggingMiddleware>();
        }

       
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        { 
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

    }
```

Strangely removing the ApiLoggingMiddleware corrects it but I am at a loss as to why and how to resolve it.

```
public class ApiLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILoggerWrapper<ApiLoggingMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private JsonSerializerSettings _serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
    
    public ApiLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ApiLoggingMiddleware> logger, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = new LoggerWrapper<ApiLoggingMiddleware>(logger);
        _env = env;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ApiLoggingSettings settings, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        Exception requestProcessingException = null;

        try
        {
            // ensure the logging context is clear
            ApiLoggingContext.DisposeCurrent();

            ApiLoggingContext.Current.Message = $"API operation {context.Request.Path.ToString()}";
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.TechnicalMessage = $"{context.Request.Method}  {context.Request.Path.ToString()}{context.Request.QueryString.ToString()}";
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.InitialiseForRequest(context.Request, settings);
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.ProductUserId = Controllers.ControllerHelper.GetUserId(context.User, configuration, raiseExceptionIfNotIdentified: false);
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.ProductUserName = Controllers.ControllerHelper.GetUserName(context.User, configuration);

            // process the request
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // this will occur if the handler itself threw an error
            // store the exception for rethrow after suitable logging has occured
            requestProcessingException = ex;
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.Errors.Add(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.InitialiseForResponse(context.Response, settings);
            ApiLoggingContext.Current.SetTimingInformation(startTime, endTime);
        }

        ApiLoggingContext contextToLog = ApiLoggingContext.Current;

        var responseCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
        if (!context.Response.HasStarted && requestProcessingException != null)
        {
            // Treat all unhandled exceptions thrown in handlers as error responses
            responseCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            contextToLog.StatusCode = responseCode;
            contextToLog.Severity = ApiLoggingContext.SEVERITY_CODE_ERROR;
        }

        // The following modifications to the logging context cannot occur earlier because they
        // depend on members which the system event context attribute supplies

        if (contextToLog.OmitQueryParameters)
        {
            contextToLog.TechnicalMessage = contextToLog.TechnicalMessage.Split('?').FirstOrDefault();
            contextToLog.Unset("Query", startsWith: true);
        }

        // Discard any key-value pairs that might trigger exceptions when recording the system
        // event information to the database (possibly something to revisit in the future)
        var pairs = contextToLog.KeyStringPairs.Where(p => p.Value.Length > 200).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
        foreach (var pair in pairs)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"Discarding key-value pair for {contextToLog.SystemEventTypeId ?? "request"} due to data truncation ({pair.Key}: {pair.Value}).");
            contextToLog.KeyStringPairs.Remove(pair.Key);
        }

        string errorId = null;

        // fire and forget logging operation.. don't want to slow down response
        #pragma warning disable 4014
        if (!contextToLog.SkipWrite)
        {
            errorId = LogResponse(contextToLog, responseCode);
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                PerformLogForContext(contextToLog, settings);
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        #pragma warning restore 4014

        // Only return the error code response for unhandled exceptions
        if (!context.Response.HasStarted && errorId != null)
        {
            var errorPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Response<string>(errorId), _serializationSettings);
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(errorPayload);
            return;
        }

        if (requestProcessingException != null)
        {
            // this was the exception thrown by the next handler
            // rethrow it now
            throw requestProcessingException;
        }
    }

    private string LogResponse(ApiLoggingContext loggingContext, int responseStatusCode)
    {
        // Do not assume every exposed handler will have the system event context annotation,
        // and note that system event types are only available after the execution of handlers
        var systemEventTypeId = loggingContext.SystemEventTypeId;

        var lastError = loggingContext.Errors.LastOrDefault();
        if (lastError != null || responseStatusCode >= ApiLoggingContext.MINIMUM_HTTP_STATUS_ERROR_CODE)
        {
            // Endpoints that fail with a result may put useful information about the cause of
            // failure so attempt to extract and log this if possible
            string reason = null;
            if (loggingContext.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
            {
                if (objectResult.Value is ApiErrorResponse errorResponse)
                {
                    var validations = errorResponse.Data.Validations != null ? string.Join(", ", errorResponse.Data.Validations) : string.Empty;
                    // Prefer logging validations as they should give better insight into why the request failed
                    reason = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(validations) ? validations : errorResponse.Data.Message;
                }
                else if (objectResult.Value is string message)
                {
                    // Handles those endpoints not following the standard error payload response format
                    reason = message;
                }
            }
            var errorMessage = $"{systemEventTypeId ?? "Request"} failed ({responseStatusCode}){(reason != null ? $": {reason}" : string.Empty)}";
            if (!errorMessage.EndsWith(".")) errorMessage += ".";
            return _logger.LogError(lastError, errorMessage);
        }
        else if (systemEventTypeId != null)
        {
            // Ignore logging successful completions of requests not mapped to a system event type
            _logger.LogInformation($"{systemEventTypeId} completed.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void PerformLogForContext(ApiLoggingContext contextToLog, ApiLoggingSettings settings)
    {
        if (contextToLog != null)
        {
            // the request, response has actually finished
            // log the results now
            if (settings?.LogToDatabase == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings?.ConnectionString))
            {
                Stopwatch databaseLoggingStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                databaseLoggingStopwatch.Start();

                try
                {

                    var writer = new ApiLoggingDatabaseWriter();

                    writer.Log(settings.ConnectionString, contextToLog);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    contextToLog.AdditionalMessages.Add("An exception occured while logging the API operation to the database.");
                    contextToLog.Errors.Add(ex);
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while logging API call to the database");
                }
                finally
                {
                    databaseLoggingStopwatch.Stop();
                    contextToLog.TimeToWriteDatabaseLogMilliseconds = databaseLoggingStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you're on ASP.NET Core 6 then you should also update your IS4 to IS5 or IS6. AFAIK, IS4 isn't fully compatible with ASP.NET Core 6.

Comment: The exception message says the exception is being thrown in `Core.WebApi.Common.Handlers.ApiLoggingMiddleware` which looks like your code, not IdentityServer's - so show us your code for that.

Comment: @Dai, added class as requested

Comment: What is `ApiLoggingContext` and `ApiLoggingContext.DisposeCurrent();`? If that's a `static` member then your code is _flat out wrong_ because you should not be mutating `static` state inside an ASP.NET Core Middleware (at least, not without using a `lock()`). That's probably the root-cause of your problem. You'll encounter the same problem (with-or-without IdentityServer) when your program services concurrent incoming requests.

Comment: @Dai ApiLoggingContext is  [ThreadStatic]

Comment: ThreadStatic doesn’t necessarily flow with async/await, that’s what AsyncLocal is for - but IMO, using either is a liability.